# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] error with glossaries

Tags: errors, glossaries, memory

I'm getting the following error when I simply include `\gls{rsh}` in my paper, and there's clearly an okay reference to `rsh` in my file `glossaries.tex`, which looks like the entry below:

```
\newglossaryentry{rsh}
{
    name={\ensuremath{R'(\hat{S})}},
    description={Function of aggregate per-capita social capital},
    sort=S-hat
}
```

This doesn't seem to be much like anyone else's query, as I'm almost certain this has something to do with my `\usepackage{glossaries}`, but I can't tell what.

Check out my project files [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzytckG985ZKfnppa1FuRDVkT3RYQ1lfaWlsU1RCbUVQMElFM3ZFZHF2WXlDT2xhZWUtMlU&usp=sharing). Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you change the `name` field to something more ordinary, like `RS`?

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately, this time with `\gls{w}`. So it looks like your intuition is right, it's something in the `name` -- but how to render the macro as a math character?

Comment: Don't use `\ensuremath`. Try `$R(\hat{S})$`, and if that doesn't work, try `$R(\protect\hat{S})$`...

Comment: ...my suggestion would be to include your project in what is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (click the link and read it) right here on this site. Next week, once your problem is solved, your project files link will become invalid, making most of the question lose its context. Providing a MWE that reproduces the problem will make it far more beneficial for you *and* the future community.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far... I'd love to provide you with an MWE. Unfortunately when I try to compile a "minimal" page such as [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzytckG985ZKdmhkU19ta282eGc&authuser=1), it works fine, but embedded in my document the stack seems to be too large.

Comment: Remove the hanging package. Why do you load it? (Or as least disable the hanging quotes with `\usepackage[notquote]{hanging}`),

Comment: Thank you so much. After all this it was `hanging`! I generally include it as part of my preamble for making references sections that aren't supported by BibTeX or biblatex. Thank you so much for finding the solution!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer An answer?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hanging package. Or at least disable the hanging quotes with `\usepackage[notquote]{hanging}`.